# How To get Youtube Videos .MP4 File using PHP OR JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, video, youtube

I am using api and know the youtube video `ID Or URL` But i want the `.MP4` file using id or link of video to play the video in videojs player can anyone help me and send me the source code in `PHP` or `Javascript`.

Like i have Youtube Video ID: `qyObyQRsHe8`
Or 
URL Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyObyQRsHe8
who i can get `.MP4` File to provide it as a src in 

`<video src=".MP4 File here"></video>`

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell than where i can ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, YouTube doesn't gives the facility of providing videos link which can be download. Alternate option is download from [Savefromnet](http://en.savefrom.net) helper by passing the youtube video link. I'm not sure whether it'll work or not but its a kind of suggestion.

Comment: that's not my question bro i know about downloading sites i want the way which will valid for all video and dynamically.

Comment: Then just add `ss` before youtube link url like `https://www.ssyoutube.com/watch?v=qyObyQRsHe8`. This will work for you but it might not give you the option for choosing multiple format.

Comment: I don't want to download video i want mp4 file i can play in own player.